# Accessing child element of dynamically genereted elements jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, children

i have following html i want to access "ABC" of h6 element on click event of div element of class "tobook". this code is generated dynamically on some controll's event
 how to do this ? thanks in advance.

```
<div class='shortcut-tiles seatdata tiles-success tobook'>
       <div class='tiles-body seatmap'>
          <span style='display:none' class='type'>Sleeper</span>
          <span style='display:none' class='seatid'> 302</span>
          <a href='#'  >
              <center>
                 <h6 data-type='text' data-title='E' class='sno' style='color:white font-size:14px !important;'> 
                   ABC</h6>
                 </center>
          </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `center` is depreciated; you shouldn't be using it to center content.

Comment: You'd access that element like you would any other element? You will how course have to wait until it's there, as you can't access the text a future element.

Comment: Thanks JoshC and Adeneo for your guidence. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', '.tobook', function () {
    var text = $(this).closest('.tobook').find('h6.sno').text();
    alert(text);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/KS4M8/)

Comment: Thanks man it worked for me. i was not trying $(this) and i was using children() api